# DAG graph and topologic order question

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find the maximum number of topological sorts on Direct Acyclic Graph of N-order. I've checked by running Depth first search algorithm on various Direct Acyclic graphs, and it looks like it is the size of Depth first search algorithm forest that created after running DFS on the graph. Or maybe I completely wrong or miss something. I also need to prove it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please spell out your TLAs.  I take it that DAG is **directed acyclic graph** and DFS is **depth-first search**.

Comment: Yes this is true. 

Comment: And for the record: TLA = three-letter acronym

Comment: Yes, sorry for wrong spelling, it's my first question here :) 

Comment: While Paul Taylor's comment also clarifies the situation, and it thus might not be necessary, you could edit the question to implement the suggestion by clicking the link 'edit' just below the question.   

Comment: Unless you specify more information about your graph, there is likely to be no good answer. To phrase your question in a more Mathoverflowese manner, you are looking for the number of [linear extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension) of a [poset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order). This is known to be difficult in general, but formulas are known for some special cases.

Comment: Now I can add "DAG graph" to my pet peeve list that includes such repetitions as "ICBM missiles", "AC current", "ATM machines", and "PIN numbers" (the last of which are occasionally called "personal PINs").